# ¿Cómo evitar que mi TextField reciba números en java con expresiones regulares?

Tags: java, javafx, regex

Quiero evitar que mi caja de texto reciba algún tipo de número y realice esta sencilla expresión. Funciona a medias, ya que cuando ingreso un número, me manda el mensaje pero si ingreso más de uno, o combinado con una letra ya no funciona.

```
String nombre=IdNombreR.getText();
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(nombre);

if(nombre.isEmpty() || mat.matches()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo Nombre esta Mal");
}else {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresión regular está bien. El problema es que estás utilizando el método [Matcher.matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()), que únicamente devuelve `true` si coincide con **todo el texto**. Es decir, tiene el mismo efecto que aplicar la expresión regular `^[0-9]$`.

En cambio, deberías usar [Matcher.find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()), que intenta la coincidencia **en cualquier lugar** del `String`.

```
if (mat.find()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El campo Nombre esta Mal");
}
```